# How do you make an app with no UI so when you open it, it runs some code

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple app that, when opened, checks what the media volume. If it is more than zero, sets it to 0 and when it is equal to zero, sets it to 100%. (I'm gonna remap the bixby button). My problem is is that when I open the app, it opens a blank UI, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ0Te.png
And I don't want it to.

```java
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int volume_level= am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        if (volume_level > 0)
        {
            am.setStreamVolume(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    volume_level,
                    0);
        }
        else {
            am.setStreamVolume(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    volume_level,
                    100);
        }
    }
```

Also it kinda doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening an activity.
This will remain open until you exit it.

Try adding a finish() at the end of onCreate()

Comment: But for a brief second it pops up. I don't want any UI ever.

Comment: AFAIK that isn't possible